# Matlab can't find member functions when directory changes. What can I do?

Tags: oop, matlab

I have a Matlab program that does something like this

```
cd media;
for i =1:files
            d(i).r = %some matlab file read command
            d(i).process();
end
cd ..;
```

When I change to my "media" directory I can still access member properties (such as 'r'), but Matlab can't seem to find functions like `process()`. How is this problem solved? Is there some kind of global function pointer I can call? My current solution is to do 2 loops, but this is somewhat deeply chagrining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

- don't change directories - instead give the file path the your file read command, e.g.

  ```
  d(i).r = load(['media' filesep 'yourfilename.mat']);
  ```

or

- add the directory containing your `process()` to the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/addpath.html):

  ```
  addpath('C:\YourObjectsFolder');
  ```

  As mentioned by [tdc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174295/669202), you can use

  ```
  addpath(genpath('C:\YourObjectsFolder'));
  ```

  if you also want to add all subdirectories to your path.

Comment: @Misha, was there a specific reason why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Jonas already mentioned `addpath`, but I usually use it in combination with `genpath`:

```
addpath(genpath('path_to_folder'));
```

which also adds all of the subdirectories of `'path_to_folder'` as well.

Comment: +1; personally I often have data in subdirectories (as the OP, apparently), so I specifically *don't* want subdirectories to clutter up my path...

Comment: Personally I've always found it easier to have a separate data directory for several reasons. The main reason is that it makes it easier to perform backups on the code only, and also it makes it easier to share the code (you probably only want to copy the data once, but the code might change many times). Whilst it seems like this sort of practice may be unnecessary if you're working on research code, it's amazing how following good practices (e.g. version control) can help you even if you're the only person working on the code.

Comment: Version control is precisely why it didn't bother me for a long time to keep results in a subdirectory ;-). `.gitignore` with `*.fig` and `*.mat` makes sure I only distribute the actual code between my development machines. But I agree it is a best practice and am moving in that direction.